Can Starship land on the moon horizontally?
Since the landing engines will be halfway up the body anyways, how about putting the landing legs to extend perpendicular and land with nose and main engine bay pointing towards their respective horizon.
Cons:
Structural integrity (but only at moon gravity)
Bigger footprint
Pros:
Greater stability, higher tolerance for slopes
Closer to the ground
Easier to access internals for converting fuel tanks to a "base"
Main engines can be started sooner after liftoff
Easier to offload cargo
Can be covered with regolith for radiation protection

additional con: main engines not usable for takeoff or landing in this orientation

@erin anne: if they dont want to use main engines for landing, i dont think they want to use them for takeoff either. but since the engines are pointing towards the horizon, they can be started sooner after liftoff without blasting the ground, so I listed it as a pro

Additional con: Making the interior and fuel tanks usable in two different directions is a lot more complicated than just having a floor that will always be 'down', especially taking load shifting into account.  To some extent that'll still be an issue with bellyflop reentry, but at least by the time you need to open any cargo doors, the whole thing should be back in an upright posture.

@DarthPseudonym - not sure  I'm following, I would assume that the interior would be laid out in a horizontal configuration as far as the floor, orientation of instrument racks, storage compartments, etc., based on how everything will be used and accessed while on the lunar surface. On-orbit it wouldn't really matter what the orientation of everything is. Unless you are referring to the vertical loads during launch from Earth (which will be uncrewed) and during powered descent. If so then yes the floor as an example has to handle structural loads in both directions.

Yes, I'm referring to firing engines and getting supplies and potentially people in and out of the vehicle safely while under two different positions.  It's not a deal-breaker, it's just a con.

@DarthPseudonym - I agree that's a con, i.e. it's in the list of complications they would have to deal with. Sort of reminds me of the Shuttle, prior to liftoff the technicians assisting the astronauts stood on the back cabin wall of flight deck and-mid deck. After landing, the same technicians (I assume it was the same ones) stood on the floor of the two decks. Same issue with equipment stowed in the cabin or payload bay, which was integrated vertically, then unstowed horizontally after landing.

Yeah, as I recall for the shuttle they had to put a sheet of plywood over the toilet to get some of the crew into their seats. Though the complicated payload cradle situation was probably the larger problem as far as landings were concerned.

Pretty sure it could land horizontally, for some value of “land” - its doing anything else after that which is in question.

I suspect that structural integrity would be a killer. Starship was designed for vertical take off and landing you can't tip it through 90 degrees, put legs on it and expect it to be ok. It will bow in the middle especially on landing. Its something that looks very doable when looking at a plastic model but when faced with the real 100 tonne+ 50m long steel cylinder its not the same.

@Slarty there could be multiple legs located to match known withstandable stresses encountered during belly entry of the other starship equipped with flaps. could be 6 or more pairs of legs distributing load. tank pressure could be increased for landing sequence too

Major problem: you can't takeoff without beaking some part of the vessel badly unless you can vertically hover upwards.

Another possible con would be that they're planning on having the landing engines near the nose to avoid digging into the surface, you'd lose that with a sideways landing

@user721108 Sure, it could be done, but it would require extra structural reinforcement (whereas landing upright re-uses the same reinforcement you need to withstand main engine thrust, so it's "free") and all those landing legs are not just extra weight but much more complexity. Six pairs of legs on the side would be a huge drag penalty if you launched with them extended, so you need a system to deploy them all after launch.

@user721108 imagine converting an modern passenger jet to land vertically. Add legs to the tail etc.

If it's correct that they're using thrusters mounted higher up for landing so as to avoid digging a crater during landing, then there would at least be a concern that landing on its side would bring the thrusters back close enough to the ground to cause a problem.

according to this paper HLS dry mass could be as low as 40tons, and it's structurally safe to transition the ship horizontally after it landed vertically.

Bad idea.
Vehicles launch and land vertically due to the incredible strength of vertically oriented thin wall cylinders. An empty thin walled aluminum beverage can can readily support the weight of a typically human when oriented vertically but even a rather light weight human can crush the same can when oriented horizontally.
Launching or landing horizontally would require extensive strengthening of the vehicle structure. This would inevitable require significantly more mass. Adding unneeded mass to the vehicle structure is the last thing vehicle manufacturers want to do.

Not disagreeing whether or not it's a good or bad idea, but it seems a bit more complicated than if a similar question was asked about landing Falcon 9 horizontally at the landing zones. Starship has been built to handle a large number of g's in a horizontal orientation when it reenters Earth's atmosphere. So it has some amount of structure already in place for horizontal loads (good). But those loads are spread evenly, compared to having say six landing legs (bad). But the landing will be in 1/6 g (good). But then internal structures built specifically for HLS would have to be heavier (bad).

@StevePemberton if it's meant to be tilted horizontally anyway to become a lunar habitat at some point, mass penalty due to all necessary equipement to tilt it on site(bad) could be saved by landing it horizontally

@user721108 - I'm pretty sure all of the tilting hardware would already be on the surface. Probably part of the hardware that will be used to move landed vehicles from the landing site to wherever the habitats will be located. Of course that's farther down the line as the initial Starship habitats will remain vertical and in place wherever they happen to land, until infrastructure is built up. Or until they decide to land Starships horizontally, which is not inconceivable, but as pointed out in this answer it most likely calculates out as a bad idea.

Starship is designed to handle aerodynamic loads entirely in the transverse direction, and has been proven to handle loads that total up to twice its body weight, as evidenced in IFT-4. If HLS preserves that level of structural integrity I expect that it should have no problem landing sideways from a structural point of view.
How it transitions from tail-landing on the main engines to belly-landing with side-thrusters, and whether the reduction in risk of tipping over outweighs the risk of this transition going wrong, is anybody's guess right now.

dsdy120 - however aerodynamic loads are spread pretty evenly across the body, similar to lying in a custom fitted Soyuz seat liner when hitting the ground in Kazakhstan. During lunar touchdown the loads would be concentrated at six points, similar to lying on six pegs during a Kazakhstan landing. Maybe not a perfect comparison but the point loads and bending loads would be very different than aerobraking. And 1/6 g doesn't really help when it comes to the moment of impact when loads are the highest.

Let's first take a look at the hypothetical advantages you outlined
Hypothetical advantages

Greater stability, higher tolerance for slopes

Just don't land on a slope? More specifically, I don't think this is a necessary requirement for HLS. There are billions of dollars being spent and hundreds of thousands of engineer-hours being poured into the Artemis program. They can simply find, select, and land at a flatter site. Sure, it will need large landing legs, but it's also not like there's wind on the moon which will mean that it needs to resist dynamic forces--just people and equipment moving around on the inside.

Closer to the ground

I don't see how this is a meaningful advantage. In fact, being further away from the ground might have several advantages, like higher solar panel mounting locations (useful for potential polar landing sites) or the ability to use starship as an antenna mast for local radio communications.

Easier to access internals for converting fuel tanks to a "base"

I think the general idea of reusing HLS or Starships to act as outer hulls for lunar bases is really cool, but if we are at the point where we are doing this (building a permanent lunar base) then we will need the equipment to manipulate entire starship hulls anyways, and a jig to tilt a starship hull from vertical to horizontal isn't that complicated or difficult.

Main engines can be started sooner after liftoff

I mean, maybe? We don't have that much experience launching things from the surface of the moon, so very "horizontal" launch trajectories may be desired, but the RCS system on Starship should be powerful enough to turn it by 90 degrees rather rapidly after hopping upwards should this be desired. Regardless, I don't think the fuel savings would be significant.

Easier to offload cargo

This is probably the most compelling point. Instead of an elevator, you could simply have a section of the hull hinge down into a ramp and then drive/roll/carry cargo directly outside.

Can be covered with regolith for radiation protection

Again, this is base-building stuff. If we are at the point in time where we have heavy regolith moving equipment on the Lunar surface, we can just lower an existing Starship from vertical to horizontal.
Evaluation
In summary, I think the only really "valid" reason to do horizontal landing on a lunar Starship is that it would be easier to unload cargo. That said, I think this advantage is rather marginal, and probably not worth redesigning the entire structure to accommodate for the new dynamic and static loading it would require.
Additionally, I think that in horizontal landing fuel sloshing would be a major issue. Consider that the Starship fuel tanks run along the hull, meaning that if it were in a horizontal position, the amount by which fuel sloshing in the forward/aft direction shifts the CG of the craft would be far more significant than the amount of slosh that is possible when it is oriented vertically. Like, imagine a plastic water bottle that only has a small amount of water left in it: when vertical it is quite stable and you can balance it on a small surface (like the cap) but when horizontal, the water can move from cap to base and make it very difficult to bring it into a stable position.

Good idea. But it would only work if Starship's thrusters were strong enough to lift the whole vessel off the ground. I have tried this idea before in KSP 1.10 Realism Overhaul, Real Solar System, just last year after IFT 1 using a self made mod that has Starship's that have Mass, volume, and aerodynamics as well as performance as close to realism as possible (the terrestrial version with legs mounted like said.) but, it would not get off the ground and instead, just break the legs ince you light the engines and crash from instability. Also, having all the landing legs on its side would make it harder to land as Starship doesn't have powerful enough thrusters to hover or land horizontally.
Verdict: It would just end in a RUD

It is valid to answer 'I tried it is KSP' but you need to be clear what source you use for the mass and performance figures, and how close you got in your model, and also any features the are not correct (eg KSP tanks being magic). Was the starship used here a terrestrial one, or one with the high mounted landing thrusters that they appear to be planning for to avoid blasting a crater during touchdown? It would seem math wise if they are good enough for vertical landing they should also work side mounted.

I would point out that due to the structure of KSP rockets in RO RP1 RSS there are a couple main inaccuracies, but still not anything that can't be accounted for.
For instance there is a manned LK lunar lander that perfectly matches performance and mass estimates when Kerbalism and RSS are used.
